# Can delete from Observable Collection but view does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I am working on the ability to add and delete rows in an observable collection.

Since the original post I have created a test app that only has the ability to delete rows from the observable collection. I populate the database externally then open it in this just to test the delete function which doesn't work. It executes the RemoveAt line, deletes from the Observable Collection but the view does not update. Here is all my code:

Model:

```
public class TestModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    private Double id;
    public Double ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
        }
    }

    private string type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            type = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Type");
        }
    }

    private decimal amount;
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Amount");
        }
    }

    private string notes;
    public string Notes
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set
        {
            notes = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Notes");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region GetData
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Transactions = DatabaseFunctions.getTransactionData();
    }
    #endregion

    #region ObservableCollections

    private ObservableCollection<TestModel> transactions;
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> Transactions
    {
        get { return transactions; }
        set
        {
            transactions = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Transactions");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public static string SharedWith;

    private Double id;
    public Double ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
        }
    }

    private string type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            type = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Type");
        }
    }

    private decimal amount;
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Amount");
        }
    }

    private string notes;
    public string Notes
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set
        {
            notes = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Notes");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public void DeleteTransactionRow(List<TestModel> SelectedTransaction, int SelectedIndex)
    {
        Transactions.RemoveAt(SelectedIndex);
    }
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="OCTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:OCTest.Properties"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
    Title="Test" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:OCTest.ViewModel">

<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="TransactionsDataGrid"  Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoCreateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete Row" Click="DeleteTransactionRow_Click"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.ContextMenu>

        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Type"  FieldName="Type" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Amount" FieldName="Amount">
                <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
            </xcdg:Column>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Notes" FieldName="Notes"/>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
</Grid>
```

Code behind that deals with the delete command and passes needed information to the view model:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowViewModel mainwindowviewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DeleteTransactionRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TestModel> selectedtransaction = TransactionsDataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<TestModel>().ToList();
        mainwindowviewmodel.DeleteTransactionRow(selectedtransaction, TransactionsDataGrid.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void MouseRightButtonUpHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TransactionsDataGrid.SelectedItem = ((DataCell)sender).ParentRow.DataContext;
    }
}
```

So hopefully someone can see why the RemoveAt doesn't update the view.

Comment: Can you post the `Add` method code?

Comment: I've added the method that adds the row to the observable collection

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of View Model and XAML as well. It's quite difficult to make any suggestions on the code that you have posted so far.

Comment: OK thank you for your help so far. I believe I have added all relevant code.

Comment: Any reason why your datagrid is called 'TestDataGrid' but you are using 'DataGrid.SelectedIndex' and then itemcollection.RemoveAt(grid.SelectedIndex); - which name is it?

Comment: Did you really name your instance object `DataGrid`, as shown in the code behind event handler? The XAML shows the name to be `testDataGrid`. If so, please never name members the same as the class name; it's incredibly confusing. If you didn't, is it a copy/paste error? Because I can't believe that code would compile otherwise...

Comment: @RagtimeWilly, so I do not waste any more of your time I have create a stripped down version of my code that loads the database and the observable collection. It has the delete function that deletes the row from the observable collection but does not reflect the deletion in the view. If you have any ideas it would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` to your view model:

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
 }
```

I'd also recommend looking into binding click events to commands in your view model rather than relying on the code behind.

Comment: It worked! I can't thank you enough. I am working on binding all click events to the viewmodel; a few things were throwing strange errors but with this working I can move onto those. I just don't get why there is such a difference between setting the datacontext in code behind vs XAML. But either way thank you!